# Best way for performing multiple search in multiple arrays

Tags: c, arrays

Consider the below table which has (Destination, Route) mapped to a `Node`.

```
Destination_id(a)   route_id(b)   next_node(c)
  4                   1             6
  7                   1             9
  7                   2             8
  8                   4             4
  7                   3             2
```

examples:

```
Given input (Destination_id, route_id) : (7,3)
Expected output : 2

Given input (Destination_id, route_id) : (4,1)
Expected output : 2
```

In other words valid mappings from the table will be:

```
Input    Ouput
(4, 1) ->  6
(7, 1) ->  9
(7, 2) ->  8
(8, 4) ->  4
(7, 3) ->  2
```

Code I've written and I am getting perfect output. Is there any other efficient method to implement this??

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
 int i,store;
 int a[5]={4,7,7,8,7};
 int b[5]={1,1,2,4,3};/// this will be always unique with respect to the search element of 'a' for eg.<7,1>, <7,2>
 int c[5]={6,9,8,4,2}; 
 int found_indices[5]; // array used to store indices of found entries..
 int count = 0; //n entries found;
 int ele_a, ele_b;
 printf("Enter the element to be search in array a\n");
 scanf("%d",&ele_a);
 printf("Enter the element to be search in array b\n");
 scanf("%d",&ele_b);
 // searching for the element
 for (i=0; i<5; i++)
 {    
     if (a[i]==ele_a)
     {
       found_indices[count ++] = i; // storing the index of found entry   

     }
  }
   if (count!=0) {
       for (i=0; i<count; i++)
       {
         if (b[found_indices[i]]==ele_b) 
         {
          store=found_indices[i];

         }
      }
   }
  printf("Element found %d ", c[store]);   
}
```

Comment: I do not understand. What should be the output if I search for 8, 2? Some more examples would help.

Comment: if '8,2' then search results in failure(no output),this is more kind of networking,

Comment: from the code if array 'a' is destination_id and array 'b' is route_id and array 'c' is next_node, the routing table contains these three arrays in a structure. if i receive 'destination_id, route_id' which is 'a,b' in the code, i will check corresponding element in 'c' array. for more clarity if  single destination has more route id, from the code destination_id is a->'7' it has corresponding route_id of '7,1' '7,2' & '7,3'. in network if receive '7,2' ('destination_id,route_id') -> i should point to value 8 in 'C' array.

Comment: confusing! Is there any chance to receive (`destination_id`,`route_id`) as (7,4)? Looking at your arrays `a[], b[], c[]` it is a failure?

Comment: Are you allowed to rearrange the array `a[]` elements for better search? of course array `b[] & c[]` will be altered accordingly without disrupting the mapping.

Comment: yes, there is no chance in receiving (7,4) . from the code the possible combinations are  (4,1) ,(7,1) , (7,2) ,(8,4) ,(7,3)

Comment: no elements in arrays are not allowed to be altered .

Comment: If the pairs are always fixed, why bother with b at all? Just figure out the index position in a, get the corresponding number from c, and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (a[i] == ele_a && ele_b == b[i]) {
        printf("Element found %d ", c[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

If mapping tables are huge then hash tables are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your program can crash for some other inputs. Because `store` is not initialized to zero. In this case consider `if (b[found_indices[i]]==ele_b)` this case never get succeeded, then finally in `printf` statment `c[store] will leads to crash.

Access that `c` array inside that `if` statement itself.

```
int c_value = 0;
....

if (b[found_indices[i]]==ele_b) 
{
   c_value=c[found_indices[i]];
}
....

if (!c_value)printf("Element found %d ", c_value);
```

Note : I hope you wont keep `0` as one of the element in `c` array.